# How to do an update statement with a left join and null values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to update a table where the values are null.  This is what I have so far,

```
    update s
    set   s.trading_partner_name = '12345'
    ,     s.edi_interchange_id_qualifier = '01'
    ,     s.edi_interchange_id = '12345'
    ,     s.application_code = '12345'
    ,     s.element_separator = '*'
    ,     s.repetition_separator = 'U'
    from  customer_edi_setting s
          right join customer c on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
    where c.class_1id like 'test customer'
```

This is updating all of the values except for the customers with NULL values in those fields.  I am trying to update the customers that have the NULL values. Any help is very much appreciated.

I am getting something like this,

```
CustomerID  TradingPartnerName  EdiInterchangeIdQualifier  EdiInterchangeId  ApplicationCode

ABC  12345  01    12345  12345  
DEF  null   null  null   null
GHI  12345  01    12345  12345
```

but but i want

```
ABC  12345  01  12345  12345  
DEF  12345  01  12345  12345
GHI  12345  01  12345  12345
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where the null issue fits?  From your questions, it sounds like you only want to update the values that, "do not have a Null value".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE s 
SET    s.trading_partner_name = COALESCE(s.trading_partner_name, '12345'), 
       s.edi_interchange_id_qualifier = 
       COALESCE(s.edi_interchange_id_qualifier, '01'), 
       s.edi_interchange_id = COALESCE(s.edi_interchange_id, '12345'), 
       s.application_code = COALESCE(s.application_code, '12345'), 
       s.element_separator = COALESCE(s.element_separator, '*'), 
       s.repetition_separator = COALESCE(s.repetition_separator, 'U') 
FROM   customer_edi_setting s 
       INNER JOIN customer c 
               ON c.customer_id = s.customer_id 
WHERE  c.class_1id LIKE 'test customer'
```

Comment: This updated the same fields it was with the original but not the fields with a NULL value.

Comment: @TonyBergeson - can you add sample data and expected output in question

Comment: does that make sense? Or do i need to clarify more? Thanks for you help!